# Carousel Controls Stuck

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have been working on a site that involves a carousel that worked fine on my server. When I uploaded it, the controls became stuck to the left side of the screen. I've tried editing the bootstrap and bootstrap.min.css, as well as my own CSS file. I've tried using developer tools to get an idea of what's wrong, but when I go to make the changes in the css files, nothing changes.

Here is a link to the site:

[Website Test](http://79.170.44.203/kelseyeliza.com/php/testzen.php)

Comment: For one you have Bootstrap css/js and jquery referenced multiple times and in the wrong dependency order basically. I would fix that before anything.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what to do with the jquery and javascript. I tried deleting one jquery and moving it to the end, but that didn't do anything either.